# Evaluate $\mathbb{P}\left(X_n=1\,|\,X_0 = 1\right)$ where $\{X_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}_0}$ is a Markov Chain with a given transition matrix $P$.

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process, diagonalization, transition-matrix

Suppose we are given a time homogeneous Markov chain $\{X_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ with state space $\mathcal{X} = \{1,2,3\}$ and transition matrix

$$P = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2/3 & 1/3 \\ p & 1-p & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

The goal is to calculate the probability $\mathbb{P}\left(X_n=1\,|\,X_0 = 1\right)$ in each of the cases where (i) $p = 1/16$, (ii) $p=1/6$ and (iii) $p=1/12$.

**Case $p = 1/16$**

I know there is a nice methodology that approaches this problem via the diagonilization of the matrix $P$. For example, in the first case ($p =1/16)$ we may find that

$$\tag{1} Q^{-1}PQ = \Delta = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1/4 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1/12\end{pmatrix},$$

where

$$Q = \begin{pmatrix}1 & -4 & -12 \\ 1 & 1 & 1\\ 1 & -33/12 & -81/36\end{pmatrix},$$

is the matrix that has eigenvectors of $P$ as columns. Solving for $P$ in $(1)$ and taking $n$-th powers we get

$$\tag{2}P^n = Q\cdot \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^n & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \left(-\frac{1}{12}\right)^n \end{pmatrix}\cdot Q^{-1}.$$

And therefore, we conclude that

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\left(X_n=1\,|\,X_0 = 1\right)&= P^{n}_{(1,1)}=\left(1,\, \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{4^{n-1}},\,\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{12^{n-1}}\right)\cdot Q^{-1}_{(1)}\\
&=\left(1,\, \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{4^{n-1}},\,\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{12^{n-1}}\right)\cdot \left(1/65,\, 1/10,\, -3/26\right)^T\\
&= \frac{1}{65}+\frac{1}{10}\cdot \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{4^{n-1}} - \frac{3}{26}\cdot \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{12^{n-1}}
\end{align},

where by $Q^{-1}_{(1)}$ I denote the first column of the matrix $Q^{-1}.$

**Any approaches for $p = 1/6$ or $p = 1/12$?**

Therefore, in the case where $p = 1/16$ there is a closed form of the probability $\mathbb{P}\left(X_n=1\,|\,X_0 = 1\right)$. However, in the other two cases where $p = 1/6$ or $p=1/12$ the matrix $P$ is not diagonizable and we cannot proceed in the same manner. Is there any way to achieve a closed form of $\mathbb{P}\left(X_n=1\,|\,X_0 = 1\right)$ in the other two cases? I tried to used the fact that $x = (1,1,1)^T$ is an eigenvector and through that to calculate the element in the $(1,1)$ position of the matrix $P^n$ but it gets rather complicated. I might missing something and I was wondering if there is any other way.

Comment: You may write to use the method generating functions. Write down the recursion relations using CK (backward) equations. Make the linear equations involving generating functions which should fairly easy to solve. Finally expand out to get the coefficient of $s^n$ to get the required probability.

Comment: Did you try to write the Jordan form of P?